# Including HTML markup in code examples when using .NET code documentation XML

Tags: html, .net, comments, documentation

.NET has a specific XML syntax for documenting the code.

The `<c></c>` and `<code></code>` tags allow to add code snippets into the comments, but apprently, they don't work well when those code snippets are made of HTML, which is a problem, because I would like to document the HTML markup output of my function.

For example, if I write the following (VB) documentation comment :

```
''' <summary>
''' <code>
''' <div class="foo">Hello world</div>
''' </code>
''' </summary>
```

It does display the "Hello world" string when I hover the function's name with my pointer, but does not show the HTML markup as is. It seems to be interpreting it instead.

Is there a way to display HTML markup as is within those comments ?

Just to be clear, I'm not trying to add styling to the documentation, I really want it to display the HTML markup itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CDATA:

```
''' <summary>
''' <code><![CDATA[
''' <div class="foo">Hello world</div>
''' ]]></code>
''' </summary>
```

For example, my product [VSdocman](https://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) has the comment editor which puts CDATA in `<code>` blocks automatically.